# The calculus of a continuum of variables

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I have trouble with this expression: $\frac{d\int_0^1 u(q_j) dj}{d q_j}$, where $\{q_j\}_{j\in\{0,1\}}$ is a continuum of variables and $u(\cdot)$ is continuously differentiable. Then, what's the result of this expression? Should it be $\frac{d\int_0^1 u(q_j) dj}{d q_j}=u'(q_j)$, just as if I take the integral as the summation sign? But if so, it seems to ignore the fact that each $j$ is inifinitesimal.

To address this kind of questions, should I refer to which part of math?

Answer (score 1):

If each $q_j$ is a real number indexed by $j\in[0,1]$, then that means you have a function $q:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$, where $q(j)=q_j$.

Your integrand is $u(q_j)=u(q(j))$. Presuming this is integrable on $[0,1]$, the result will not depend on $j$ or $q_j$. It doesn't make much sense to differentiate with respect to $q_j$ when considered as a function.

For example, if $q(j)=j$ for all $j\in[0,1]$, then your integral is

$$\int_0^1 u(q_j)\, dj =\int_0^1 u(j)\, dj =U(1)-U(0)$$

where $U$ is an antiderivative of $u$. The integral is just a constant. Whatever you differentiate it with respect to, you will get zero (unless there are some other variables you have not made explicit).

---

Note if $q$ were differentiable then you would have

$$\frac{d u(q(j))}{dj}=u'(q(j))\cdot q'(j)=u'(q_j)\cdot q'(j)$$

---

In what context does the integral arise?